# Meaning of textures

Tags: matrices, image-processing, python

Could someone explain me what does the "Sum Average" mean in equation 6th in the following link.
http://murphylab.web.cmu.edu/publications/boland/boland_node26.html

Its related to creation of image texture (2d array) from an image (2d array).
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is horrible notation. It's defined in [this paper](http://haralick.org/journals/TexturalFeatures.pdf). The symbol $p$ is multiply overloaded with various meanings that are inconsistent when taken literally according to standard notational conventions. The symbol $p_{x+y}(k)$ doesn't refer to a quantity indexed by $x+y$; it's only a function of $k$, with "$x+y$" merely indicating that this is the probability for the sum of the indices to take the value $k$; that is, in conventional notation, $p_{x+y}(k)=\textsf{Pr}(X+Y=k)$. In terms of the probabilities $p(i,j)$ in the co-occurence matrix, $p_{x+y}(k)=\sum_{i+j=k}p(i,j)$. Thus, the quantity referred to as the "sum average", $\sum_kkp_{x+y}(k)$, is the expected value of the sum of the gray levels of adjacent pixels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a newbie of mathematics, I could not understand what exactly does the sum average mean? How would you define it in few sentences without mathematical notation? If possible, could someone show it's calculation using Python so that it be much clear.

Answer (score 0):

From  the paper Joriki references, Appendix I, the authors define $4$ marginal-probability matrices (vectors) from:

> $p(i,j)=(i,j)^{th}$-entry in a normalized gray-tone spatial-dependence matrix.

Namely:

$$p_x(i)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N_g}p(i,j)$$
$$p_y(j)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_g}p(i,j)$$
$$p_{x+y}(k)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_g}\sum\limits_{j=1, i+j=k}^{N_g}p(i,j)$$
$$p_{x-y}(k)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N_g}\sum\limits_{j=1, |i-j|=k}^{N_g}p(i,j)$$

which give sums across the horizontal, vertical and both diagonals.

So I am guessing the authors meant to define all $4$ 'sum averages' using the standard definition of expection, $E(X)=\sum xP(X=x)$.